# Keras: zero division error

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to get the activation values for each layer in this baseline autoencoder built using Keras since I want to add a sparsity penalty to the loss function based on the Kullbach-Leibler (KL) divergence, as shown [here, pag. 14](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder_2011new.pdf).

In this scenario, I'm going to calculate the KL divergence for each layer and then sum all of them with the main loss function, e.g. *mse*.

I therefore made a script in Jupyter where I do that but all the time, when I try to compile I get `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`. 
This is the code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses

x_train = np.random.rand(128,128).astype('float32')
kl = K.placeholder(dtype='float32')
beta = K.constant(value=5e-1)
p = K.constant(value=5e-2)

# encoder
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='same', 
name='encoder',input_shape=(128,128,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# get the average activation
A = K.mean(x=model.output)
# calculate the value for the KL divergence
kl = K.concatenate([kl, losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(p, A)],axis=0)

# decoder
model.add(Conv2D(filters=1,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='same', name='encoder'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
B = K.mean(x=model.output)
kl = K.concatenate([kl, losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(p, B)],axis=0)
```

Here seems the cause

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _normalize_axis(axis, ndim)
989     else:
990         if axis is not None and axis < 0:
991             axis %= ndim <----------
992     return axis
993
```

so there might be something wrong in the mean calculation. If I print the value I get

`Tensor("Mean_10:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`

that is quite strange because the weights and the biases are non-zero initialised. Thus, there might be something wrong in the way of getting the activation values either.

I really would not know hot to fix it, I'm not much of a skilled programmer.
Could anyone help me in understanding where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be doing calculations outside layers. The `model` must keep track of all calculations.

- If you need a specific calculation to be done in the middle of the model, you should use a `Lambda` layer.
- If you need that a specific output be used in the loss function, you should split your model for that output and do calculations inside a custom loss function.

Here, I used `Lambda` layer to calculate the mean, and a `customLoss` to calculate the kullback-leibler divergence.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses

x_train = np.random.rand(128,128).astype('float32')
kl = K.placeholder(dtype='float32') #you'll probably not need this anymore, since losses will be treated individually in each output.
beta = beta = K.constant(value=5e-1)
p = K.constant(value=5e-2) 


# encoder
inp = Input((128,128,1))
lay = Convolution2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='same', name='encoder',activation='relu')(inp)

#apply the mean using a lambda layer: 
intermediateOut = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x),output_shape=(1,))(lay)


# decoder
finalOut = Convolution2D(filters=1,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='same', name='encoder',activation='relu')(lay)

#but from that, let's also calculate a mean output for loss:
meanFinalOut = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x),output_shape=(1,))(finalOut)

#Now, you have to create a model taking one input and those three outputs:
splitModel = Model(inp,[intermediateOut,meanFinalOut,finalOut])
```

And finally, compile your model with your custom loss function (we will define that later). But since I don't know if you're actually using the final output (not mean) for training, I'll suggest creating one model for training and another for predicting:

```
trainingModel = Model(inp,[intermediateOut,meanFinalOut])
trainingModel.compile(...,loss=customLoss)

predictingModel = Model(inp,finalOut)
#you don't need to compile the predicting model since you're only training the trainingModel 
#both will share the same weights, you train one, and predict in the other
```

Our custom loss function should then deal with the kullback.

```
def customLoss(p,mean):
    return #your own kullback expression (I don't know how it works, but maybe keras' one can be used with single values?)
```

---

Alternatively, if you want a single loss function to be called instead of two:

```
summedMeans = Add([intermediateOut,meanFinalOut])    
trainingModel = Model(inp, summedMeans)
```

Comment: I partially agree, and that's because an average activation should be computed for each layer, i.e. it's just *one* value since it's the mean. And the same happens to be `p`. In this scenario, `A` and `B` and `p` will be tensors of shape `shape=(1,1)` or, as I saw when printing ` `shape=()`. In this way, all the KL divergences should be added to the main loss. Maybe I edit the question so to be more accurate.

Comment: I agree that KL is a single number, but since `p` is an argument to a loss function expecting tensors of the shape of the output, I think it should be shaped (but maybe the system can work it around itself). --- But have you tried splitting the model like in the answer? That calculates losses for each layer, trains based on all losses and doesn't use KL.

Comment: Yes, I just made a trial but at the end I get negative loss values and negative activations (and that should not be possible because of the `relu`). I think I haven't figured out completely why should I split my model since I don't want two losses, but just one which is the sum of two different.

Comment: I splitted it because it was the only way I could think of getting intermediate outputs into a loss function. Perhaps there are better solutions. Having two losses in the model is very similar to summing those losses. It will try to minimize both losses, which is minimizing the sum. You could try to sum all values using `Lambda` layers instead of leaving them to custom losses. But then, the result of the `Lambda` would not be useful for the next layer, so you would have to split it anyway.

Comment: and what if I defined my own `kullbach_leibler` function? So, for each layer, I can take the activations, compute their mean and feed the function. `p` is given. And I could eventually define a loss function that is the sum of `mse` and the sum of all the `kullbach_leibler` values. In this case (yet tried) I still have problems in the `K.mean` calculation. Perhaps that should be the real question, i.e. *how to get activation values and use them*.

Comment: Ah! I think I entirely forgot the "K.mean" in your question.... see my update then. Still, `K.mean` should be inside layers. For that, unfortunately I have no other solution than splitting the model. If you don't like having lots of outputs and one loss for each, you can create a `summedMean = Add()([intermediateOut,meanFinalOut])` and pass `summedMean` to the `Model`

Comment: Also updated the layers for using the `Functional API`. I wasn't really sure `Sequential` would support splitting that way.

Comment: I also found that you can implement a custom loss function where you can use intermediate layers. This may look like `return losses.mean_squared_error(yTrue,yPred) + K.sum(losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(p,intermediateOut))` and seems working, so to have a model with one input and one output. It works, but I'm not sure about the effective correctness of such a formula. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hmmm. Compare the two forms. I'm afraid of that one :p